# Need help finding a formula for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

A sequence $(x_j)^\infty_{j=0}$ satisfies

$x_1=1$, and for all $m \ge n \ge 0 $ $x_{m+n}+x_{m-n} = \frac12 (x_{2m}+x_{2n})$.

I have to find a formula for $x_j$ and then I can prove that later for homework. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try $x_n := n^2$, then we have $(n+m)^2 + (n-m)^2 = 2(n^2 + m^2) = \frac{1}{2}((2m)^2 + (2n)^2)$.  Use induction.

Comment: Thanks that definitely helps a lot. Would I use induction on $n$?

Comment: Yes. You could just use $m := \left\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ and $n := \left\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ for $k \geq 2$. Then $n-m = 1$, $n+m = k$ or $k-1$ (need to do casework based on $k$ odd or $k$ even.  Then you get an expression for $x_{2m}$ via strong induction.